# ASP.NET failing to call an unmanaged dll after initial request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll

So I have an unmanaged C++ dll which I am calling from my ASP.NET application, it has a single entry point and a couple of structures for passing data.  If I create a C# console app to call the dll it works fine.  If I hook it in to my asp.net app running on my local WinXP machine (IIS 5.1) then it works fine.

When I publish it to our development environement which is running Windows 2003 and IIS 6 then the first 1 or 2 calls works fine but then it simply stops responding. I'm getting no error messages, warnings etc... but I am fast running out of hair!

I've set the virtual directory which runs the asp.net app up inside of its own application pool but this seems to have had no impact.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: A shot is the dark - but issue could be related to how asp handles thread creation and worker processes. Read your answer, I don't think the dll is actually failing but rather a thread related issue. Also considered properly disposing of any references you may have to the unmanaged code at the end of every request. Don't rely on the GC.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that it stops responding? You could try putting logging statements that would trace the input/output around the call to see where exactly it blocks. Also make sure you check the server Event Log where unhandled ASP.NET errors are written. As a last resort you could install Visual Studio remote debugging tools (`msvsmon.exe`) on the server and step through the code by attaching to the corresponding `w3wp` process. Actually the debugging tools doesn't require installation, a simple copy is enough (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger`).

Comment: In the asp.net code there is logging around the invoke so I can see the asp.net logging saying that it has started and finished.  There is also logging in the dll at the earliest opportunity and this is not emitting any logging at all.  Also nothing in the server event long.

Comment: Actually I've found the problem, not sure why the difference between the two environments but it is unrelated to my initial question

Answer (score 0):

The failure appears actually to be with the C++ code itself, it has some code to handle locking for a threaded environment and this appears to be failing.  Not sure why it works on my local machine and not the dev environment but that's another question.

Thanks all